# HighStocks change AJAX parameters

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp, highcharts

My highstocks chart fetches JSON data from Yahoo and data from is structured like so "www.blahAAPLblah.com".

I want to change the value of AAPL in the URL to other company ticker symbols so that I can fetch the data and display it on my chart. If I change the string manually to GOOG then it will work fine. Also if I put `var ticker = 'GOOG'` and change the URL to `"www.blah" + ticker + "blah.com"` then this also works fine.

If I have a user input box and have `var ticker = document.getElementById('userInput').value;` then everything stops working.

Do you have any suggestions at all?

Here is my code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/SgvQu/

**UPDATE** I have attempted to use JSONP to perform the request but the chart is still not loading.

```
    var closePrices = new Array();
    var dateArray = new Array();
    var timeStampArray = new Array();
    var timeClose = new Array();

function jsonCallback(data, ticker) {

            console.log( data );

            //Put all the closing prices into an array and convert to floats
            for(var i=0; i < data.query.results.quote.length; i++)
            {
                closePrices[i] = parseFloat( data.query.results.quote[i].Close );
            }

            //displays the values in the closePrices array
            console.log( closePrices );

            //Put all the dates into an array
            for(var i=0; i < data.query.results.quote.length; i++)
            {
                dateArray[i] = data.query.results.quote[i].date;
            }

            //Convert all the dates into JS Timestamps
            for(var i=0; i < dateArray.length; i++)
            {
                timeStampArray[i] = new Date( dateArray[i] ).getTime();
            }


            for(var i=0; i<data.query.results.quote.length; i++)
            {
                   timeClose.push( [timeStampArray[i], closePrices[i]] );
            }

            timeClose = timeClose.reverse();
            console.log ( timeClose );

            //displays the dateArray
            console.log( dateArray );
            console.log( timeStampArray );

            // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1
            },

            title : {
                text : ticker + ' Stock Price'
            },

            series : [{
                name : ticker,
                data: timeClose,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
        });
}

function createChart() {  

    var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22' + ticker +'%22%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222013-01-01%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%222013-02-25%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=?';
    //Ajax call retrieves the data from Yahoo! Finance API
    $.ajax( url, {
        dataType: "jsonp",  
        success: function(data, status){
            console.log(status);
            jsonCallback(data, ticker);
        },
        error: function( jqXHR, status, error ) {
            console.log( 'Error: ' + error );
        }
    });
}


//Function to get ticker symbol from input box.
function getTicker() {
        var ticker = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
        createChart(ticker);
    }
```

Comment: It looks like a problem with JSON cross domain problem, because when I use static link (go to it in the browser, content is displayed) but with the same link (without variable) in code it breaks. So I advice to check this and use i.e JSONP if it is possible.

Comment: It doesnt work because you have not defined getTicker() function.

Comment: Sorry I only pasted the JSON functions, there is a getTicker() function defined like so : `function getTicker() {
     ticker = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
     createChart(ticker);
 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Sebastian Bochan for pointing me in the right direction with JSONP. I now have the chart functioning correctly :)